# Sharepoint 2013 MMS Accssing Taxonomy terms issue

Tags: sharepoint-2013, taxonomy

I am facing issue while accessing taxonomy for anonymous users, for windows authenticated users its working fine. This taxonomy is used for building site navigation and below is the code I am using to get the records

var navTermSet = TaxonomyNavigation.GetTermSetForWeb(site.RootWeb, StandardNavigationProviderNames.CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider, true);

This code is wrapped under run with elevated privilege and this code returns 2 term set and under each term set there are many terms presents, but if I run this code under windows authenticated user it will return all the terms else it will return only 2.

Under each termset it will show count as 0

Below verification I have done from my end
1) Site is anonymous and taxonomy hidden list is having anonymous enabled and provided view permission for everyone
2) Added MMS app pool account, Web app pool account to MMS db
3) Provided full access to both the account in term store admin access @ central admin(Service)

Can any one please guide me how I can fix this

Regards
Anand

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the site collection and recreated it, then it started working.